# Force Index does not work on aws mysql

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, execution-plan, amazon-rds-aurora

I have a table `sales` with a compound index on (user_id, eastern_date, state)

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    user_id int not null,
    eastern_date date not null,
    state varchar not null,
    sales_count int not null,
    sales_amount float not null,
    UNIQUE KEY `user_date_state` (`user_id`, `eastern_date`, `state`)
    ...
)
```

Total number of rows is ~ 60MM

I then explain a query on it for 3400 records

```
explain
select * from sales 
where (`user_id`, `eastern_date`, `state`) IN (
    (1, "2022-01-01", "NY"),
    ... 3399 more tuples
)
```

And it shows me that it uses the index `user_date_state`

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sales | "pmin p2020 p2021 p2022 p2023 p2024 p2025 p2026 pmax" | range | user_date_state | user_date_state | 309 | NULL | 3400 | 100.00 | "Using where" |

I then explain a query on it for 3401 rows (1 more match) and it no longer uses the index.

```
explain
select * from sales 
where (`user_id`, `eastern_date`, `state`) IN (
    (1, "2022-01-01", "NY"),
    ... 3400 more tuples (1 more match)
)
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sales | "pmin p2020 p2021 p2022 p2023 p2024 p2025 p2026 pmax" | range | user_date_state | NULL | NULL | NULL | **60000000** | 50.00 | "Using where" |

I then include a `FORCE INDEX` clause

```
explain
select * from sales 
FORCE INDEX (user_date_state)
where (`user_id`, `eastern_date`, `state`) IN (
    (1, "2022-01-01", "NY"),
    ... 3400 more tuples (1 more match)
)
```

but it **still** does not use the index which seems to indicate that force index did not change anything. What am I missing? (Thank you)

I am using version 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.09.1 and the table is an INNODB table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row constructors such as

```
(a,b,c)) IN ((1,2,3), (5,6,7))
```

were not efficiently acted on.

As a workaround, I suggest you insert those 3400+ rows into a temp table with the same 3 column names, then do

```
JOIN temp_table
    USING (`user_id`, `eastern_date`, `state`)
```

Rumor has it that row-constructors are being improved (someday).

As a side note, consider getting rid of `id` and promoting that Unique key to be the Primary Key.

I suspect (without any concrete evidence) that the existence of Partitioning is adding to the sluggishness.

One more thing to look at:  Check that the collation on `state` is the same as that of the connection `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`